# How to replace numbers inside of a string using Regular Expression

Tags: php, python, regex, string

I am quite new in regular expression so I am having confusion in replacing numbers inside an string.

```
a="12ab34cde56"
```

I want to replace it by `12abXXcde56`

```
b="abc1235ef"
```

I want to replace it by `abcXXXXef`

```
c="1ab12cd"
```

I want to replace it by `1abXXcd`

I am trying those in python and in php, but with no luck. This is what I had in my mind:

```
^([0-9]+)([a-z]+)(.*)([a-z]+)([0-9]+)$
```

Comment: So "1f4d6f5" --> "1fXdXf5"? What about "1  f  5  g f5  6 h 8"?

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried so far? You'd learn a lot more if you we can guide you with your own code.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes you are right, any numbers that are not leading or trailing a string would be replace by X

Comment: @MartijnPieters, This is what I have in my mind, ^([0-9]+)([a-z]+)(.*)([a-z]+)([0-9]+)$ could you please explain my fault

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt: With that, you are assuming that there are at least a leading or trailing digit `+`, but it may not be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture all digits that is not leading or trailing:

```
(?<!^|\d)\d+(?!$|\d)
```

Then in Python, you can supply a function that replace the match with corresponding number of `X`.

For PHP, you can enable PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE to know the position of the match, and loop through the list of matches and process them.

Note that with the regex above `"  5 ddds"` will be changed into `"  X ddds"`

Answer (score 0):

We substitute every group of digits (`\d+`) surrounded by non-digits (`\D`)  in the string s by `X`'s .

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\D)\d+(?=\D)',lambda match : 'X' * len(match.group(0)) , s)
```

Comment: he's replacing only those digits which are within alphabets.

Comment: Your code might fail for these inputs: "sdf34", "4df34df34f34fff8"

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern catch the string to remove in group 1:

```
^.*[a-z]+(\d+)[a-z]+.*$
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?31djp).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re1 = re.compile("([\d]*[a-zA-Z])([\d\w]+)([a-zA-Z][\d]*)")
re2 = re.compile("([\d])")

s = "4f6g6h7"
def x(matchobj):
    return ''.join([matchobj.groups()[0],
        re2.sub('X', matchobj.groups()[1]), matchobj.groups()[2]])

print re1.sub(x, s)
```

---

Update: The original method won't work for case`"4f6g6h7"` or any string only has one alphabet char between digit.

If using two regular expression instead of one is acceptable. The following code should work for u.

```
import re
re1 = re.compile("([\d]*[a-zA-Z])([\d\w]+)([a-zA-Z][\d]*)")
re2 = re.compile("([\d])")

s = ['12ab34cde56', "abc1235ef","1ab12cd", "4f6g6h7"]

def x(matchobj):
    return ''.join([matchobj.groups()[0],
        re2.sub('X', matchobj.groups()[1]), matchobj.groups()[2]])

for ss in s:
    print ss, '->', re1.sub(x, ss)

>>>
12ab34cde56 -> 12abXXcde56
abc1235ef -> abcXXXXef
1ab12cd -> 1abXXcd
4f6g6h7 -> 4fXgXh7
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility with the stock `re` module appears to be a replace function, for example:

```
xs = ["12ab34cde56", "abc1235ef", "1ab12cd"]

import re
for x in xs:
    print x, re.sub(r'(\D)(\d+)(\D)', lambda m: m.group(1) + 'X' * len(m.group(2)) + m.group(3), x)
```

With the more advanced [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module you can use variable-width lookaround assertions:

```
import regex
for x in xs:
    print x, regex.sub(r'(?<=\D\d*)\d(?=\d*\D)', 'X', x)
```

Comment: Please check whether the first solution can replace this case correctly: `"4f6g6h7"`